# AlarmManager repeating

Tags: android

здравствуйте. моя программа работает по такому принципу. пользователь задает время, а в это время нужно постоянно каждый день вызывать notification.
я это сделал, но есть косяки, и вообще у меня чувство что я неправильно реализовал это.

вот код

```
package com.actionbarsherlock.sample.fragments;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;

public class TimeAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

     NotificationManager nm;

     @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      nm = (NotificationManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
      CharSequence from = "Nithin";
      CharSequence message = "Crazy About Android...";
      PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
        new Intent(), 0);
      @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,
        "Crazy About Android...", System.currentTimeMillis());
      notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, from, message, contentIntent);
      notif.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + "com.actionbarsherlock.sample.fragments" + "/"+ R.raw.song);
      notif.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

      nm.notify(1, notif);
     }
    }
```

...

```
package com.actionbarsherlock.sample.fragments;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;

public class AutoStart extends BroadcastReceiver
{   
    NotificationManager nm;
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {   
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"))
        {
          nm = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
              CharSequence from = "Nithin";
              CharSequence message = "Crazy About Android...";
              PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                new Intent(), 0);
              @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,
                "Crazy About Android...", System.currentTimeMillis());
              notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, from, message, contentIntent);
              notif.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + "com.actionbarsherlock.sample.fragments" + "/"+ R.raw.song);
              notif.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

              nm.notify(1, notif);
        }
    }
}
```

....

```
 public void setRepeatingAlarm(int hour, int minute) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, TimeAlarm.class);
      PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
      intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
      Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
      calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
      calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
      calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
      am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
        24*1000*60*60, pendingIntent);
     }

private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timePickerListener = 
        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int selectedHour,
        int selectedMinute) {
        hour = selectedHour;
        minute = selectedMinute;
        am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        setRepeatingAlarm(hour,minute);
        // set current time into textview
        tvDisplayTime.setText(new StringBuilder().append(pad(hour))
                .append(":").append(pad(minute)));

    }
};
```

проблема в том что когда задается время которое уже прошло, тогда notification вылетает сразу, нужно сделать чтоб оно вылетело через 24 часа

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я делал так:

```
    long alarmTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    if (alarmTime < System.currentTimeMillis() + 500)
        alarmTime += 24*60*60*1000;
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            alarmTime, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
            pendingIntent);
```